# Google Invisible reCaptcha not working as expected

Tags: php, invisible-recaptcha

We have two forms at the Landing page "Signup & Login" & we have to integrate invisible recaptcha on both the forms.

Below is the script loading above the closing of body tag:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

SignUp & Login forms are rendered via bootstrap modal on the Home page.
SO, i have to manage both the forms with single callback mentioned in the script. Some times it working & some times not.!

When i am executing the below script, it start showing the challenge box as i already attached screenshot.
    setTimeout(function(){ grecaptcha.execute(login_captcha); },1200);

[image]

Below is my JS Code:

```
function loadGoogleCaptcha(captcha_selector){
        var onloadCallback = function(captcha_selector) {
            if (captcha_selector=='login_captcha'){
                login_captcha = grecaptcha.render(captcha_selector, {'sitekey' : sitekey, 'callback' : captchaLoginCallback});
            } else if (captcha_selector=='signup_captcha'){
                signup_captcha = grecaptcha.render(captcha_selector, {'sitekey' : sitekey, 'callback' : captchaSignupCallback});
            }
        };
        onloadCallback(captcha_selector);
        if (captcha_selector=='login_captcha'){
            setTimeout(function(){ grecaptcha.execute(login_captcha); }, 1200);
        } else if (captcha_selector=='signup_captcha'){
            setTimeout(function(){ grecaptcha.execute(signup_captcha); }, 1200);
        }
    }
    function captchaLoginCallback(token){
        grecaptcha.execute(login_captcha);
        //var captcha_response = grecaptcha.getResponse(login_captcha);
        //console.log('Login: '+token+' === '+captcha_response);
    }
    function captchaSignupCallback(token){
        grecaptcha.execute(signup_captcha);
        //var captcha_response = grecaptcha.getResponse(signup_captcha);
        //console.log('Signup: '+token+' === '+captcha_response);
    }
```

I hope now i am clear in my query

What i am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `var onloadCallback = function` is a _local_ variable, only available inside your `loadGoogleCaptcha` function - that won’t work. Your callback function must be globally available, otherwise the recaptcha script won’t find it.

Comment: @04FS: I have tried with trick also, but if didn't worked

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] then, currently you have just shown us a bunch of functions without any proper explanation how and where they get called.

Comment: @04FS: I have edited my post, just have a look and let me know id you need any other details.

Comment: That still shows the very issue I mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: What i need to change in my code, can you please suggest.?

Comment: You need to start by making the onload callback function you specify in the script URL _globally_ available.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200824/discussion-between-saurabh-kackar-and-04fs).